# ¿Cómo recargar componente en Angular?

Tags: angular, componentes

en primer lugar gracias por entrar a la pregunta.

Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar recargas de página. Actualmente tengo una serie de rutas con este aspecto:

':env/:element',':env/:element/:id'

La primera de las rutas es un carrusel de "cards" el cual te redirige a la segunda ruta en función del elemento que elijas. ¿Cuál es mi problema?

Mi proyecto de angular cuenta con un sidebar(caja azul) que sirve para la nevagación y un elemento donde se añaden los distintos datos (caja verde) en función de lo seleccionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que ciertos de los elementos del sidebar redirigen a un mismo componente (aunque la información varía), en el momento que realizas la navegación de un elemento a otro que comparten componente, la información que recibo desde el servicio no se actualiza.

Este sería el aspecto con el cual solicito la información, el parámetro this.env si me lo recoge y actualiza, en cambio el servicio smart4p no actualiza la información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál puede ser una posible solución?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código en forma de texto por favor? Puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta (el botón editar se encuentra abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas) 
y pegando el código en la pregunta. Para darle formato, puedes seleccionar todo el código y presionar las {} que están arriba de la caja de texto.
En este link se explica la importancia de NO poner capturas de código en una pregunta: 
[Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imagenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejecuta el servicio `smart4p` dentro del callback donde se recibe el valor de `env`.

```
 constructor(){
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((r: any) => {
           this.env = r.env
          // aqui se debe ejecutar el servicio `smart4p` porque aqui es donde
          // se recibe el valor de `env`.
       })
    }
```